# Changing key in Mifare 4K Card

Tags: rfid, mifare, contactless-smartcard, access-keys

Can anyone please tell me how to change a key in a Mifare 4K classic card.

What I tried was

```
<newKeyA> + access bits + <KeyB>
0xAA 0xAA 0xAA 0xAA 0xAA 0xAA 0X78 0x77 0x88 0x69 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
```

But the key refuses to change. The default configuration is `0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the access keys of a sector on a MIFARE Classic card, you simply have to update that sector's trailer block.

So, for instance, if your current key B is `FFFFFFFFFFFF` (and the current access conditions *permit* writing of the sector trailer with key B), you would first authenticate for that sector with that current key B.

Then, you would create your new sector trailer:

```
<new key A> | access bits | general purpose byte | <new key B>
```

For instance:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA 787788 69 BBBBBBBBBBBB
```

to have key A set to `AAAAAAAAAAAA` and key B set to `BBBBBBBBBBBB` with these access conditions:

- Trailer block: C1=0,C2=1,C3=1 → Sector trailer is writable using key B only; access bits/GPB can be read with key A or B.
- Data blocks: C1=1, C2=0, C3=0 → Write is possible using key B only; read is permitted with key A or B.

Finally, you can write the new sector trailer to the trailer block, which is the last block (i.e. block 3) of each sector.

Comment: What about for higher sectors which has 16 blocks?